# Is there any design pattern I can apply onto an Android Location Manager helper class?

Tags: android, design-patterns, memory-management, location

I'm writing a **location manger helper class** for my android project. The helper class should be able to use and retrieve location information from anywhere in the application module. I was wondering if there are any **appropriate design patterns** I can apply onto it.

I'm thinking of using a design pattern like **singleton** to the location helper class, because I can retrieve location information instantly without having an individual location manager object for every activity class. But it has an **issue when location updates are being removed.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably some sort of a singleton class so you can access from anywhere in your code to get the required info.

The thing is that the current location manager in android is already implemented as a service so basically what you are probably looking for is some sort of a "Facade"

see:

Facade - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

Singleton - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Services - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_layers_pattern